# How to stop the responses continuously from gps L89 module through uart and single command to receive the latitude and longitude parameters?

Tags: gps, quectel

Able to get the responses from gps qucetel L89 module through uart .

How to stop the responses continuously  from gps L89 module through uart and single command to receive the latitude and longitude parameters?

Answer (score 0):

```
     $PSTMCFGMSGL,<listid>,<rate>,<listlow>,<listhigh><cr><lf>
```

This is the command that can stop all the messages depending on the setting  of listlow and listhigh which is given in the datasheet google for L89 quetel protocol specification.
You can control at what rate the data can be send .